What do ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) inside square brakets mean for class and function declarations in Python 3.12+?
What does T, *Ts, **P mean when they are used in square brackets directly after a class or function name or with the type keyword?
class ChildClass[T, *Ts, **P]: ...

def foo[T, *Ts, **P](arg: T) -> Callable[P, tuple[T, *Ts]]:

type vat[T, *Ts, **P] = Callable[P, tuple[T, *Ts]]


See complementary questions about ** and * for function parameters and arguments:

What do ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) mean in a function call?
What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?


Python 3.12, in relation to PEP 695, introduced some grammar changes which bring some features from the typing library into the syntax of the language itself.
In short: Each of the 0-to-2-starred expressions T, *Ts, and **P is a type parameter. They are used as a parameters for type parameter lists which can be used for functions, classes and the type statement to create a TypeAliasType.
A type parameter list, encapsulated by [] may follow the name of a class, function, or typevar after a type statement and will create a generic. Type-checkers can infer the type of attributes and calls for example:
class ClassA[T]:
    def method1(self) -> T:
        ...

def create[T, *Ts](arg: T, *args: *Ts) -> ClassA[tuple[T, *Ts]]:
   ...

a = create(1, 2, 3)    # a inferred as ClassA[tuple[int, int, int]]
t = a.method1()        # t inferred as tuple[int, int, int]


Inside a type parameter list the three different amounts of asterisks have the following meaning:

A non-starred identifier, e.g. T is the equivalent to typing.TypeVar and is interpreted as a single type.

An identifier prefixed with a single asterisk, e.g. *Ts, is the equivalent to typing.TypeVarTuple and is interpreted as a tuple of types. The single-asterisk prefix * before a TypeVarTuple is equivalent to using typing.Unpack which can be seen similar to a normal unpacking just for types, e.g. tuple[int, *tuple[int, str]] is equivalent to tuple[int, int, str]. Using a TypeVarTuple makes it variable what types are unpacked.

Two asterisk before an identifer, e.g. **P, denote a ParamSpec, which in turn stands for the parameters of a callable.


The three different variants of 0-2 asterisk differentiate between these types.
A type parameter list for function and classes defines the listed type parameters in their local scope only, similar to typing.Self which refers to the type of the encapsulating class inside a class' body.
The following example from the documentation illustrates most usages:
def overly_generic[
   SimpleTypeVar,
   TypeVarWithBound: int,
   TypeVarWithConstraints: (str, bytes),
   *SimpleTypeVarTuple,
   **SimpleParamSpec,
](
   a: SimpleTypeVar,
   b: TypeVarWithBound,
   c: Callable[SimpleParamSpec, TypeVarWithConstraints],
   *d: SimpleTypeVarTuple,
): ...

Furthermore a ParamSpec's args and kwargs attributes can also be used to annotate both and only both function parameters prefixed with * and **
def usage_with_kwargs[
   SimpleTypeVar,
   **SimpleParamSpec,
](
   c: Callable[SimpleParamSpec, SimpleTypeVar],
   *c_args: SimpleParamSpec.args,
   **c_kwargs: SimpleParamSpec.kwargs
): ...


As you might have noticed the syntax also allows for colons : in a type parameter list, these address some of the other paramters of typing.TypeVar, allowing to define an upper bound type of a type variable or constraints that state a type is either type A or B or ...
TypeVarWithBound: int # equivalent to TypeVar("TypeVarWithBound", bound=int)
TypeVarWithConstraints: (str, bytes),  # equivalent to TypeVar("TypeVarWithConstraints", str, bytes)


The same holds for type parameter lists when used for class declarations and the type statement, just that in Python versions <3.12 we have to use typing_extensions.TypeAliasType or typing.Generic, the former beeing the functional equivalent of the type statement.
Quoting PEP 695:
Defining a generic class prior to python 3.12 looks something like this:
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

_T_co = TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True, bound=str)

class ClassA(Generic[_T_co]):
    def method1(self) -> _T_co:
        ...

With the new syntax, it looks like this, omitting the need to use TypeVars directly.
class ClassA[T: str]:
    def method1(self) -> T:
        ...


For the type statement it is similar:
from collections.abc import Callable
type call[T, **P, *Ts] = Callable[P, tuple[T, *Ts]]

is equivalent to
from typing import ParamSpec, TypeVarTuple, TypeVar, Unpack #, TypeAliasType # if Python >= 3.12
from typing_extensions import TypeAliasType # backport
from collections.abc import Callable
T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')
Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")

call = TypeAliasType("call", Callable[P, tuple[T, Unpack[Ts]]], type_params=(T, P, Ts))


I suggest that this question-and-answer pair be made community wiki. The upcoming Python 3.13 is introducing another grammar change (type parameter defaults) and it is expected that later versions will amend these changes to support bound and constrained TypeVarTuples as well. Wiki-fying will allow the content to be updated by anyone rather than just you and high-rep users.
